# How to update multiple form values with one reducer action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hook-form, redux-toolkit

I am building a multi step form and I am using react-hook-form and redux-toolkit.

Everything works, but on some pages I have multiple input elements (ex. goal and height).

**My current code:**

```
const rootSlice = createSlice({
    name: "root",
    initialState: {
      goal: "",
      height: "",
      age: "",
      username: "",
    },
    reducers: {
      chooseGoal: (state, action) => {
        state.goal = action.payload;
      },
      chooseActivityLevel: (state, action) => {
        state.activity_level = action.payload;
      },
      chooseYourAge: (state, action) => {
        state.age = action.payload;
      },
      chooseYourUserName: (state, action) => {
        state.username = action.payload;
      },
    },
  });

  const goal = useSelector((state) => state.goal);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { goal, activity_level },
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    dispatch(chooseGoal(data.goal));
    dispatch(chooseActivityLevel(data.activity_level));
  };
```

I was wondering if I can hook multiple form values to one reducer something like this:

```
chooseGoalAndHeight: (state, action) => {
        state.goal && state.height = action.payload;
      },
// And dispatch it like this:

dispatch(chooseGoalAndHeight(data.goal, data.height));
```

Also is it okay to initialize a form element that will have a number input with empty string?

Comment: Pass the form data as an object to the action.

Comment: @yudhiesh thanks how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. This is one of the three main problems in the redux world. See [Redux Problems](https://redux-cool.js.org/docs/introduction/problems#problem-2-define-a-single-action-in-multiple-reducers)

You can solve that problem clearly and beautifully, using [redux-cool](https://redux-cool.js.org) lib which has [Global and local Actions](https://redux-cool.js.org/docs/concepts/global-and-local-actions) capability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it where I changed the `initialState` to be an array of the objects you want to add from the form instead of just an object as you probably want to store multiple instances of the form data. Then I combined all the reducers into a single reducer and added in a prepare callback which prepares the `action.payload` to ensure it is the same format as the object of the `initialState`. You can read more about [Preparing Action Payloads here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data#preparing-action-payloads).

```
const rootSlice = createSlice({
  name: "root",
  initialState: [
    {
      goal: "",
      height: "",
      age: "",
      username: "",
    },
  ],
  reducers: {
    submitForm: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare(goal, activity_level, age, username) {
        return {
          payload: {
            goal,
            activity_level,
            age,
            username,
          },
        };
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Then you would use the reducer like so just passing in properties of the form as per the `initialState` objects structure.

```
dispatch(submitForm(data.goal, data.activity_level, data.age, data.username));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. I recently implemented it.

```js
const initialState = {
    data: {},
};


const rootSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'currentUserDetails',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addUserInfo: {
            reducer(state, action) {
                state.data = {
                    ...state.data,
                    ...action.payload
                };
            },
        },
    },
});

export const {
    addUserInfo
} = currentUserDetails.actions;
export default rootSlice.reducer;



// Inside your Component
const data = {
    goal,
    activity_level
};

//dispatch
dispatch(addUserInfo(data));
```